# Can Multiple jQuery Validate rules be applied in a single Datatables Jeditable field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, datatables, jeditable

I know this is possible on a regular form field (as well as simple). I have a jquery datatables (www.datatables.net) pulled from an Ajax source. I allow certain persons within our organization to update records directly from this table using the jeditable plug-in featured. The plug itself works great. To validate the input, I include the jquery validate plug in and make the call as shown here:

[Demo of validation within page using jeditable, datatables, jquery and validation](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inline-validation.html)

As you can see by the demo, validation rules are called using :

> { class : "required" }

and so on. I have tried adding multiple rules to a single field (along with rules available in the validation plug in which dont seem to function here at all) but can't get it work. I have tried using:

> { class : { required : true, email : true } }

as I would have using regular validation but no luck. Anybody had luck on this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch#u6c42U6ig8Y/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.editable.js&q=editable%20package%3ahttp://jquery-datatables-editable%5C.googlecode%5C.com), `cssclass` is added using `.addClass()`:

```
if (settings.cssclass != null) {
    input.addClass(settings.cssclass);
    ...
}
```

so, you should be able to simply supply the classes in a string delimited by spaces:

```
{ cssclass:"required email" }
```

Comment: @JM4 The source code linked here is no longer available. I need the demo_validation css. I am also using jEditables with DataTables and need inline validation using jQuery validation plugin.

Comment: @SilentAssassin - then search for it on Google. I don't maintain the project.